# Can I show data is sorted when not sorted by dataTables

Tags: datatables

I am using the https://datatables.net/ jQuery plugin to display client side tabular data.

The data for my table is pre-sorted so I don't want the overhead of dataTables doing the first sort. I have set aaSorting to [] so that dataTables does not sort the data.

My problem is that I would like the header style to show which column the data is sorted by and when that column is sorted for it to toggle the sort order.

I tried a cheat of the following which displays the way I want but I have to click twice to change the search to descending.

```
dataTableOptions.fnInitComplete = function (oSettings, json) {
    $table.find('th:first').addClass('sorting_asc');
};
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default sort direction of your target column to 'desc' by using `asSort` as documented [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref). This would sort your table in descending order on the first click. You would still to set the class of `th:first` to `sorting_asc` on init.

```
// Using aoColumns
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumns": [
      { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] }, // assumes you are targeting column 1
      ...// other columns
    ],
    ...// other configuration
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I have tried that and it doesn't sort at all once I have set that although it does display the icon correctly. I'll create a sample and post a link to it or it's going to be hard to explain.

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle with my sample - http://jsfiddle.net/259r8/1/.  The first bit of JavaScript is what you posted above.  It displays correctly but clicking in the column heading does not sort the data. The commented out JavaScript doesn't display that the data is sorted but can be sorted.  I need both, i.e. data does not get sorted on first load (initial sort is done server side), it displays that it is sorted and you can still click on the column heading to do the sort.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Much appreciated.  The new fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/259r8/4/